# Configuring Element API 1.2.1 Plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-elementapi

I'm running Craft CMS 2.6.2972 so I had to use [the older Element API plugin](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api/tree/1.2.1).

I have downloaded the zip and then copied just the "elementapi" file in the zip to the plugin's folder.

Then I installed the plugin in the admin panel.

Then I made a file craft/config/elementapi.php with the contents

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'news.json' => [
            'elementType' => 'Entry',
            'criteria' => ['section' => 'news'],
        ]
    ]
];
```

But if I hit the URL `<myserver>/api/news.json` then I get the following error:

```
2017/05/12 17:31:47 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.404] exception 'Craft\HttpException' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\controllers\TemplatesController.php:59 Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Craft\TemplatesController->actionRender('api/news.json', Array)
#1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\framework\web\actions\CAction.php(109): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(Craft\TemplatesController), Array)
#2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\framework\web\actions\CInlineAction.php(47): CAction->runWithParamsInternal(Object(Craft\TemplatesController), Object(ReflectionMethod), Array)
#3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\framework\web\CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#4 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\framework\web\CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#5 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\framework\web\CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#6 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('render')
#7 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('templates/rende...')
#8 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\etc\web\WebApp.php(290): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#9 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\framework\base\CApplication.php(185): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#10 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#11 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\public\index.php(14): require_once('C:\\inetpub\\wwwr...')
#12 {main} REQUEST_URI=/api/news.json
---
```

What might be wrong?

This is running on IIS and I've added .json to the mime types for the site.

This error is the same error as an unhandled link/route. So seems like it's not picking up the config or I have the wrong URL. The plugin did install ok.

Comment: If you're hitting `/api/news.json` in the browser, pretty sure the endpoint should be defined as `'api/news.json' => [`.

Comment: Thanks That was it althought the example doesnt show it like that. If you want to make this an answer can give you credit.

Comment: Fair enough... done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hitting `/api/news.json` in the browser, you'd want to define the endpoint as `'api/news.json'` as well.  i.e.

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'api/news.json' => [
            'elementType' => 'Entry',
            'criteria' => ['section' => 'news'],
        ]
    ]
];
```